# How to use local files with this script from chatdownloader? Python

Tags: python

I want to use a local file (for example, an exported file from chatdownloader) rather than an url, is it possible?
[chatdownloader](https://github.com/xenova/chat-downloader)

```
from chat_downloader import ChatDownloader
import time

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ih2WTyY62J4' # Change URL here

prev_time = 0
chat = ChatDownloader().get_chat(url, start_time=prev_time)
for message in chat:                        # iterate over messages
    if prev_time is not None and 'time_in_seconds' in message:
        time.sleep(max(message['time_in_seconds'] - prev_time, 0))

    chat.print_formatted(message)           # print the formatted message

    prev_time = message.get('time_in_seconds')
```

I don't really know what to do. I'd be happy if you can tell me your thought!

Comment: Nope.  You have the source.  You can see that It only accepts URLs.  You can certainly save the messages in whatever format is convenient for you.